# How to persist docker Images through multiple dind containers?

Tags: docker

I am working on a project where I am scaling multiple **dind containers** `Docker in Docker`:

**docker-compose.yaml**

```yaml
version: '3.8'

networks:
  net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dind-images:

services:
  # DinD Container Configuration
  agent:
    image: docker:dind
    volumes:
      - 'dind-images:/var/lib/docker/image'  # Persist docker images through dind containers
    privileged: true    
    tty: true
    networks:
      - net
```

and I am running this compose file with:

```sh
docker-compose up -d --scale agent=2
```

As you can see I am mapping `/var/lib/docker/image` to a volume called `dind-images` through multiple containers the problem is whenever I try to run this in one of the containers `docker image pull image_name` then run docker `docker image ls` I only get the image name listed in the only dind container I used pull command on but won't show on other containers.

**PS: WHEN I RESTART CONTAINERS WITH `docker-compose down|up` I CAN SEE IMAGES ON ALL OF THEM**

Am I missing something and would that affect next runs?

> When I run `docker image pull image_name` on the other containers it takes only a second to pull (which means that it finds the image data) but when i run `docker image ls` it doesn't show the image).
>
> > I feel like there's other data I need to include in the volume but I don't know what exactly.

Comment: Can you show how you're using this from another container, or are the other containers running inside the DinD container?  DinD is kind of complicated to use ("which Docker am I actually talking to" takes some reasoning); can you use the host's Docker socket instead, or update your application to avoid operations that would need access to it?

Comment: (I would expect multiple Docker daemons sharing the same underlying storage to have problems; if you want to run two nested Docker daemons, each would need a separate volume.)

Comment: Afaik, if you mount the actual docker socket, then you can create sibling containers. These would be available on your host system. So images are pulled on the host as well.

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't get exactly what are you trying to understand, but am currently running separate DinD containers from my host machine, and also in my case I am not supposed to use my host docker socket.

Comment: Docker on docker wouldn't help because that will in fact use all volumes/networks/containers... of my host docker engine, but in my use case I need to run dind containers separately I am just trying to persist Images so I won't download them all over again through each one of them and thanks ^_^.

Comment: I believe the answer to the linked question applies here. If your question is different, please tag me here with how it's different so we can get this reopened.

Comment: @joshmoto I am using a volume not a bind-mount

Comment: @BMitch don't you think there is a big difference between the whole `/var/lib/docker` and `/var/lib/docker/image` directories? I am only trying to persist docker images, while in the linked question the op is trying to persist `/var/lib/docker` not `/var/lib/docker/image`

Comment: The image directory contains lots of pointers to other directories, it's not a complete list to share images. In their question, the use case still appears to be the same: "Actually I want to have my images shared."